# How To Access Namespace Created In Any Folder Into Code Behind For C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces, three-tier

I have created a folder in my website in asp.net C# usindg VS'10 ,,

Now i added a class into that folder with namespace as under:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ThreeTierSample.BLL
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Summary description for Student
  /// </summary>
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }


    public void insert()
    { 

    }
  }
```

}

I want to use this namespace into code behind file for that i'm trying to include namespace with statement :

```
using ThreeTierSample.BLL
```

but the problem is that it will not allow me to add this namespace even it doent show in intellisence.

Help me to resolve this issue.

Below is the screen shot of my project hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: Move this class to App_Code folder or create new class under App_code folder and copy your content from existing file.

Comment: You can also create folder under App_Code folder and add you class file

Comment: That's working fine ,, and i knew that trick but i want that folder(BLL) outside the app_code folder and want to access class inside that folder, and that's the goal of posting this question.

Comment: Then create one new Class Library Project as SpiderCode suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that your student class is in different project of the same solution and you want to use that class in some other project let's say web project where you have all of your UIs.

So we have to projects in one solution.

1. Student.BLL
2. Student.Web

To solve your problem you must have to add your **Student.BLL** project as an reference into your **Student.Web** project.

Below are the steps to add the project as an reference. :

1. Right click on the Student.Web project
2. Select Add -> Reference
3. One popup window will be displayed
4. In right panel of that popup, select solution
5. In middle panel your list of projects will be displayed. Select Student.BLL from there and click OK as mentioned below :

[image]

Now you can access your class with the namespace.

**Note :** I have observed in your snapshot that you have wrote **ThreeTierSamle.BLL** instead of **ThreeTierSample.BLL** (You have forgotten **'p'** in **'Sample'**)

Comment: Its not a different project as i have mention further ,, BLL is a folder of same project inside which all classes are resides ,so i cant get student.bll in a projects tab

Comment: If both classes are in the same project, it should work using namespace. can your question with the image of solution explorer ?

Comment: i have posted snapshot ,,Please review it.

Comment: check my updated answer. I have added **Note** at the end of answer. Please check that. It will resolve your problem. and don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ThreeTierSample.BLL;

namespace ThreeTierSample.BLL
{
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
    } 
    public void insert()
    {     
    }
  }
}

public class TestingClass
{
Student myStudent = new Student();  //  THIS IS OUTSIDE THE ThreeTierNamespace
                                    //  and will work                                      

}
```

you may have the threetier namespace nested in another that's why it's not showing up in our intellisence